# Where should I ask what tools or settings I should use to make a backup of a cloud Debian server for local Hyper-V deployment?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I go to ask this question?

> I'm trying to make a backup of a cloud-based server running Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) to download and deploy into a local Hyper-V environment for testing upgrade viability and complications.
>
> I've looked into various tools and I think considering the hardware discrepancy involved the best method would be using the dump/restore package. What is the best place to find documentation or instruction for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Server Fault.

But don't ask for (links to) documentation or instruction on a scenario. Just ask how to do it. If there are good pre-written guides you will probably be linked to them, along with quotes or descriptions. If there aren't, any answers will *be* the guides.

Since questions are better when they are more specific, any progress you make planning or executing this will improve the question and prompt more detailed and tailored answers, although of course you should hold off on any steps that might have unforeseen lasting consequences.